# Subsetting SPSS data imported into r with package haven?

Tags: r, subset, r-haven

I've used the package `haven` to read SPSS data into R. All seems ok, except that when I try to subset the data it doesn't seem to behave correctly. Here's the code (I don't have SPSS to create example data and can't post the real stuff):

```
require(haven)
df <- read_spss("filename1.sav")
tmp <- df[as_factor(df$variable1) == "factor1",]
tmp <- tmp[!is.na(tmp$variable2), ]
```

The above df has "NA" scattered throughout. I expected the above to subset only the data, keeping only rows with variable1 with "factor1" and discarding all rows with NAs in variable2. The first subset works as expected. But the second subset does not. It removes rows, but NAs are still present.

I suspect the issue has something to do with the way `haven` structures the imported data and uses the class `labelled` instead of an actual factor variable, but it's over my head. Anyone know what could be happening and how to accomplish the same?

Here's the structure of `df`, `variable1` and `variable2`:

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   4573 obs. of  316 variables:

> str(df$variable1)
Class 'labelled'  atomic [1:4573] 9 9 9 14 8 8 2 4 8 16 ...
  ..- attr(*, "labels")= Named num [1:18] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:18] "factor1" "factor2" "factor3" "factor4" ...

> str(df$variable2)
Class 'labelled'  atomic [1:4573] 3 NA 3 NA 3 NA 1 1 NA NA ...
  ..- attr(*, "labels")= Named num [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "Sponsor" "Not a Sponsor" "Don't Know"
```

Comment: Can you post a small subset of your data? Say just `head(df)`?

Comment: Ok, I've added some info about df and the variables.

Comment: what does `unclass(df)` give you?

Comment: Does the first subset (`tmp <- df[as_factor(df$variable1) == "factor1",]`) really work? SPSS data sets imported with haven are in most cases atomic resp. numeric. `factor1` is the value _label_, not the _value_ itself. So you should subset with numeric values, like `tmp <- df[df$variable1== 1,]`. There is a package dedicated to working with labelled data, [sjmisc](https://cran.r-project.org/package=sjmisc), which you may find useful. And there is a "vignette" with an introduction into working with labelled data: http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/sjmisc

Comment: Yes, it did work for the first one. Thank you for pointing me to the package and vignette, I'll read up on them and get back to this.